# How do I get this code to center a div id?

Tags: css

```
#border-search {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 10px auto !important;
    margin-right: 10px auto !important;
    width: 100% !important; 

}
```

here is js fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/matsuiny2004/7dms170p/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `text-align:center;` to your CSS. Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7dms170p/2/

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS and it will center. `text-align:center;`.

And you don't need to use `!important` in this...